# How to zigzag numbers in floyd's triangle pattern?

Tags: java

I have found a way for zigzag matrix but I am willing to find same as clean code for triangle pattern.

Example:

```
input = 3
```

Output:

```
1
32
456
```

I already coded a numbered matrix code here:

```
int k=0;
int t=1;
int n=4;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        k+=t;
        System.out.print(k);
    }
    k=k+n+t;
    t=-t;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
1234
8765
9101112
16151413
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: to print zigzag pattern in floyd's triangle with my same logicwith some modifications.

Comment: And what is the problem you're currently faceing? Just pasting your code doesn't really counts as a problem statement. Please edit your question and add more information

Comment: I changed the above code as for triangle pattern ,where is it is not printing even rows which present in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int n = 6;
    int num = 0;
    int step = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        // num : (i² - i + 2)/2 .. same + i - 1
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            num += step;
            System.out.print(num);
            System.out.print(' ');
        }
        num += i + (1 + 3*step)/2;
        step = -step; // zig resp. zag
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Helpful was numbering *i* as row with exactly *i* elements.

Yielding

```
1 
3 2 
4 5 6 
10 9 8 7 
11 12 13 14 15 
21 20 19 18 17 16
```

The problem was that every row `i` of `i` numbers has a lowest value `(i² - i + 2)/2`,
and for the *next* zigzagging number one needs to consider the following step.

From the last row number to the first row number of the next line has two cases:

- step -1
- step 1

Both formulas of both cases can be unified by the step.

```
step   i   num
  +    1   1 -> 4     += i + 2
  -    2   2 -> 3     += i - 1
  +    3   6 -> 11    += i + 2
  -    4   7 -> 10    += i - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will work:

```
public static void zigZag(int rows) {
    int current = 1;
    int increment = 1;
    for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
        int width = row + current;
        for (int element = current; element < width; element++) {
            System.out.print(current);
            current+=increment;
        }
        System.out.println();
        current += row + 0.5 - (0.5*increment);
        increment = -increment;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** just a note because I suspect your question might be homework motivated, so it might help if you can understand what's going on instead of just copy-pasting.

All that really needed to change was to use the external loop variable (the one that was originally creating your matrix square, which I've called row) in the inner loop which prints the individual elements of the row.

This is then used to calculate the first element of the next row. The increment value does the same as it does in your original, but now it can also be used to have the zig-zag pattern go up in integers other than 1.

Comment: i know how to find my solution in different way  but  it  is need to be similar to be the above code where i want some modifications to play on it.

Comment: As far as I can tell this is structurally almost identical to your code above. The outer loop iterates over the rows, and the inner loop iterates over the elements in each row, then the current value is adjusted after each new row is completed. The variables could be changed back to have the same name if that would help? Is there a reason you need it to be so similar to your original code?

Comment: I don't find that the above code produce expected result but ,and yes code should be similar to the above matrix code Thanks but even your code didn't find to solve the problem as mentioned.

Comment: @vigneshkarunakaran the code above absolutely does give the expected result. If you call `zigZag(3)`, the result is the same as your required output. The code is similar to the original question. I might be able to help you more if you provide a bit more information about why you need the implementation to look a specific way?

Comment: it produce result as 1  next line followed by 2 3 ,but kindly see the above output of expected triangle its a clean zigzag

Comment: I think you might have input another answer. My code produces 1 followed by 32 etc.

Comment: Sorry Chris i checked it twice..!,

Comment: Sorry @vigneshkarunakaran, it definitely does work, [here's the output](https://ideone.com/aASHfN)

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the top of the triangle (1) will be row 1, all subsequent even rows are printed in reverse.  Knowing that you can try something like this:

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int triangleSize = 5;
        int counter = 1;
        int rowSize = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= triangleSize; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                // Reverse number sequence
                int reverseCounter = counter + rowSize - 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < rowSize; j++) {
                    System.out.print(reverseCounter--);
                    counter++;
                }
            } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < rowSize; j++) {
                    System.out.print(counter++);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
            rowSize++;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep track what row you're on (rowSize) and what value you're on (counter).  When you're on an even row you have to start with the highest value that row will have and count backwards from it, but still increment your normal counter (int reverseCounter = counter + rowSize + 1).

Result:

```
1
32
456
10987
1112131415
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i need a solution  which can be derived from my similar  code which is in the description.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I coded it for you:

```
public class TriangleNum{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    getTringle(5);
  }

  public static void getTringle(int j){
    for (int i =0; i<j;i++) {
      System.out.print(i+ "\r" );
      for (int k =0; k<i;k++) {
        System.out.print(k+ "\t" );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't reverse the order of the numbers on each subsequent row.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Using C Language
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){ 
int n,count=1,k=1;
printf("Enter number of lines:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
    if(i%2==1){printf("%d",count);count++;}
    else{printf("%d",count);count--;}}
    count=count+k;
    if(i%2==1){k=k+2;}
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking it in java language.